# Issue with "ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string" in an API Call

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, string.format

I'm using Python 3 for this.

Basically, I'm making a API call using urllib and getting the error:

*"ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string"*

I have looked at a variety of other solutions but they don't seem to work.

Basically what I am doing is:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def query_person(first, last):
   person_request = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.querysite.com/content/search/index:AUTHOR?query=authlast%28%27{last}}%27%29%20AND%20authfirst%28%27{first}}%27%29&'.format(first=first,last=last))
   return(person_request)

print(query_person("John", "Doe"))
```

The actual API will not be reproducible since it requires an API key (ommited obviously) as well as the need to be on a verified network.

I think the issue has to do with **"{last}}%27%29%20AND%20authfirst%28%27{first}}"** having an extra bracket.  For example, if I wanted to just query it in my url bar without python or .format(), it would look like:

```
http://api.querysite.com/content/search/index:AUTHOR?query=authlast%28%27Doe}%27%29%20AND%20authfirst%28%27John}%27%29&
```

or more specifically: **Doe}%27%29%20AND%20authfirst%28%27John}%27%29&**

If I use the latter method in python, I have no issues, but it does not allow me to input names to query of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double up on your single brace if you want it to remain in the string:

For example:

```
'{first}}}'.format(first='John') == 'John}'
```

In your case:

```
person_request = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.querysite.com/content/search/index:AUTHOR?query=authlast%28%27{last}}}%27%29%20AND%20authfirst%28%27{first}}}%27%29&'.format(first=first,last=last))
```

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  This is what I thought and wasn't sure why I was getting an error even though I was doing this.   Turns out I was adding in an extra bracket accidentally each time (I recently switched IDEs to Sublime Text 3).  Will accept your comment as correct once it allows or delete this if people down vote me :(